# How to calculate distance covered by the beam? (friction force problem)

Tags: physics

**Question:**
**A uniform beam of weight W and length L is initially in position AB. As the cable is pulled over the pulley C, the beam first slides on the floor and is then raised, with its end A still sliding. If $\mu$ be the coefficient of friction between the beam and the floor, calculate the distance a that the beam will slide before it will begin to rise.  Ans. $L(1-\mu)$**
[image]
**My try:**
I drew the F.B.D. like this,
[image]
Now, as the beam slides, so,
Force for which the beam slides F = $P\sin 45^0-\mu N$
and from equation of equilibrium,
$$\Sigma F_y=0\\
\implies P\cos 45^0+N=W\\
\implies N=W-P\cos 45^0$$
$\begin{align}\\
\therefore &F = P\sin 45^0-\mu (W-P\cos 45^0)\\
&{\implies \begin{aligned}\\
\frac Wg\times a'=P\sin 45^0&-\mu (W-P\cos 45^0)\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
&{\implies \begin{aligned}\\
a'&= \frac gW[P\sin 45^0-\mu (W-P\cos 45^0)]\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
\end{align}\\$
But, I can't understand how I can relate the distance a with the acceleration a', as there is no final velocity given. Please anyone suggest any approach.

Comment: I believe you would have better luck receiving an answer over at Physics Stack Exchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SomeGuy I had already asked in that website(though another question), but it closed my question and told that in that website no homework problem is allowed.

Comment: Please don't close my question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404018/find-friction-coefficient-given-initial-and-final-velocity , this question was of similar to mine and was asked in this website. So that, I asked.